# Basic understanding of SMTP: mail from

Tags: email, smtp

I'm implementing an application in ruby on rails (although this is a minor detail) that needs to send emails. Everything works fine, but I'm surprised cause when the app sends a mail, as long as it's authenticated against the smtp server, the sender it's going to be whatever it's specified in mail from. My point is, I can authenticate in a smtp server with "myuser@mydomain.com" and "mypassword" and be able to send a mail in which the recipient would see whichever address I want as sender.
This doesn't make any sense for me, and I'm sure it can't be so easy. I know it's surely a completely silly question for most of you, but would really appreciate anyone could make it clear for me.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You authenticate as a generic user, it is only an accident that your login name is similar to a mail address. And yes, usually you can send mail with any reverse-path (reverse-path is the address in the MAIL FROM SMTP command). This may be necessary, for example a list manager uses VERP and sends mails with many unique reverse-paths.

However, some mail servers and mail administrators do place restrictions on the reverse path and the address in the From header. Especially, if the server signs the message.

Moreover, if the receiving server checks SPF records, it is useless to impersonate a remote domain, even if it is allowed, because the mail will be rejected anyway (if the domain publishes an SPF DNS record).